# Interaction between import, class and match...case in Python

Tags: python, class, import, match, case

I'm puzzled by how `from ... import ...`, class constructor and `match...case` in Python interact between each other.

Given there are two modules, `foo` and `bar`. `foo` imports `CONST` from `bar` and tries to use it in `Foo` class `__init__()` within `match...case` construction. This gives `UnboundLocalError`.

The minimal reproducer is below.

`foo.py`:

```
from bar import CONST

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, var):
        print(CONST)
        match var:
            case CONST:
                print("hit")

foo_instance = Foo(1)
```

`bar.py` (*single line only*):

```
CONST = 1
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "…/foo.py", line 10, in <module>
    foo_instance = Foo(1)
  File "…/foo.py", line 5, in __init__
    print(CONST)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'CONST' referenced before assignment
```

If I remove `match...case` from `__init()__` or if I replace it with a simple `if`, the error disappears, and `print(CONST)` prints `1` as I expect.

`pylint` also warns about the code:

```
foo.py:7:17: W0621: Redefining name 'CONST' from outer scope (line 1) (redefined-outer-name)
foo.py:5:14: E0601: Using variable 'CONST' before assignment (used-before-assignment)
foo.py:7:17: C0103: Variable name "CONST" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
```

but I do not really understand it. What's the issue with scoping here?

Could you please explain the behaviour to me?

Python interpreter version in use: `3.10.7`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case CONST` acts like an assignment in this case. This is because the case statements can be used to capture the values being matched as well. So python tries to create a new variable named `CONST` in that scope. So the previous `print(CONST)` acts like it's trying to access a variable that doesn't exist until the match is executed.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements

> Patterns can look like unpacking assignments, and can be used to bind variables:

```
# point is an (x, y) tuple
match point:
    case (0, 0):
        print("Origin")
    case (0, y):
        print(f"Y={y}")
    case (x, 0):
        print(f"X={x}")
    case (x, y):
        print(f"X={x}, Y={y}")
    case _:
        raise ValueError("Not a point")
```

Comment: Thank you. So basically that means that one of the solutions would be to add `global CONST` before calling `print(CONST)`?

Comment: Moving the import within the method would also work